# Move-Item doesn't move file

Tags: powershell

I've tried to rename a csv with powershell and then move it automatically to another folder, when there's no file.
Originally, the csv-name looks like this: *import_9999_2020-08-13_132238.csv* but the part with 9999 can also include just 2 or 3 digits.
My actual Code looks like:

```
#Import of path and target-path
$path = "\\network-path\subfolder\subfolder\subfolder\subfolder\subfolder1\"
$target_path =  "\\network-path\subfolder\subfolder\subfolder\subfolder\subfolder2\"


#endless loop
$a=$true
while($a -eq $true){
    $Files = gci $path
    $TargetFiles = gci $target_path
    
    #wait 5 minutes if path is empty
    if(($Files).Count -eq 0){
        sleep -Seconds 300
    }

    #if path is filled with one or more files
    else {
        #if file in target-path is processed (from another program)
        if(($TargetFiles).count -eq 0){
            #rename and move the latest file
            get-childitem -path $path -Filter "import_*.csv"|
                where-object { -not $_.PSIsContainer } | 
                sort-object -Property $_.CreationTime | 
                select-object -last 1 |
                Rename-Item -NewName {($_.Name.Substring(0,($_.Name.Length)-22))+".csv"} |
                Move-Item -Destination $target_path +"$($_.Name).csv"
        }
         sleep -Seconds 20
    }
}
```

It works partly and renames the csv, but it doesn't move it to the target-path. The path is correct, i've copied it from the Windows-Explorer.
Any Ideas, why the program doesn't work completely? Thanks

Comment: one problem with using the pipeline like you have is knowing EXACTLY what is in the current `$_` in the current pipeline stage. i bet your final move command is NOT seeing the renamed file ... instead it seems likely to be seeing the old name ... and that aint there any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For better readability, I would split the code where you find the original file, rename it and move it to the target path into several lines.
Also, `Move-Item` can rename the file aswell, so no need to do a `Rename-Item` first:

```
$file = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter "import_*.csv" -File |
            Sort-Object -Property $_.LastWriteTime | 
            Select-Object -Last 1

# create the new name for the file.
# or use regex:  $newName = '{0}{1}' -f ($file.BaseName -replace '(_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_\d+)$'), $file.Extension
$newName = '{0}{1}' -f (($file.BaseName -split '_')[0..1] -join '_'), $file.Extension
# now move the file and rename at the same time
$file | Move-Item -Destination (Join-Path -path $target_path -ChildPath $newName)
```

<sup>I changed `CreationTime` to `LastWriteTime` to really get the latest file.

I also added the `-File` switch to the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet, because only for old PowerShell versions you need to use `where-object { -not $_.PSIsContainer }`</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass it down the pipeline add `-Passthru` to the `Rename-Item` cmdlet

```
Somefile.txt | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.basename + "abc" + $_.ext} | # nothing in the pipeline

Somefile.txt | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.basename + "abc" + $_.ext} -Passthru | # now the new named fileinfo object is in the pipeline, contained in automatic variable $_
```